# regular expression for subnet of ip address

Tags: regex

I am looking to have only  0|64|128|192 in my last octet (for subnet with /26 mask). The first code for validating ip address works fine. But I am unable to get the validation for the last octet working. Not sure what I am doing wrong here

I am looking for 172.17.251.64 should be allowed 172.17.251.200 should not be allowed

```
<input name="ipAddress" title="Input data should be in IP Address Format" type="text" pattern="^(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2([0-4]\d|5[0-5]))\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2([0-4]\d|5[0-5]))\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2([0-4]\d|5[0-5]))\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2([0-4]\d|5[0-5]))$">

<input name="subnet" title="Input data should be in Subnet Format" type="text" pattern="^(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2([0-4]\d|5[0-5]))\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2([0-4]\d|5[0-5]))\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2([0-4]\d|5[0-5]))\.(0|64|128|192))$">
```

Comment: Note you do not need `^` and `$` in the pattern attribute.

Comment: already tried that. see my second line of code

Comment: See [`^(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2([0-4]\d|5[0-5]))\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2([0-4]\d|5[0-5]))\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2([0-4]\d|5[0-5]))\.(0|64|128|192)$`](https://regex101.com/r/gO3sH0/1)

Comment: [regex101.com](https://regex101.com) is your friend.

Comment: Thanks. The extra bracket was causing the issue :)  regex101.com is wonderful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To understand where you are wrong, go to the regex101.com, and use the `/x` option with PCRE flavor and try to break the expression into lines to check the structure of the regex. See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/gO3sH0/2):

```
^
  (\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2
    ([0-4]\d|5[0-5])
  )
  \.
  (\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2
    ([0-4]\d|5[0-5])
  )
  \.
  (\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2
     ([0-4]\d|5[0-5])
  )
  \.
  (\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2([0-4]\d|5[0-5])) # THIS SHOULD BE REPLACED!!!
$
```

So, use

```
^(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2([0-4]\d|5[0-5]))\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2([0-4]\d|5[0-5]))\.(‌​\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2([0-4]\d|5[0-5]))\.(0|64|128|192)$ 
                                                                                                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gO3sH0/1)

Note that you may remove the `^` and `$` from the regex since `pattern` attribute value is anchored by default (it is enclosed with `^(?:` and `)$`).

Comment: Thanks for adding the demo and showing the gmx option